# Wordpress autologin guest to a specific user

Tags: wordpress

may I somehow autologin all guest to a specific user?

Random guest visit the homepage and I need to log him as "Admin2" (or another name, that doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet to log in anyone which is visiting your site and he's not logged in, just place it at very bottom of functions.php :

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = 'admin2';
        $creds['user_password'] = 'PASSWORD_ON_PLAIN';
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        wp_redirect(home_url());
    }
```

Replace the password string and this will do the trick.

Comment: O solved it earlier with similar code, but this code seems more elegant :) Thanks a lot